# jqueryのelse if文の条件分岐

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

`iconName.indexOf('icon07.png')` の画像データがある時は `<option value="40610" selected="">` にselectのデータが入らない処理したいので、どうしても処理を発生しない条件がほしいです。

このようにコードを書いてもうまくいきません。
どのように改良すればいいでしょうか。

```
if(calendarId)
{
    var iconName = $("[ownerid='" + ownerid + "']").next().children('.user-table').children('dt').first().children('img').attr('src');

    if(iconName.indexOf('icon04.png') != -1) isHuman = true;
    else if(iconName.indexOf('icon07.png') != -1) isHuman = false;  
    else isHuman = false;

    if(isHuman) {
        url += 'allGroupUuserList=' + calendarId;
    }
    else if{
    }
    else
    {
        url += 'allfacilitieList=' + calendarId;
    }
}
```

```
<div class="col-xs-5 form-group"> 
<label class="col-xs-12 control-label mb5" style="float: left;" for="group_registered_userlist">参加</label>
<select name="invitedUserCalendarResourceIds" class="col-xs-12 form-control input-sm" id="group_registered_userlist" size="8" multiple="">
<option value="40610" selected=""> (ここにデータを選択された状態にしたい) </option> </select>
</div> 

<td class="col-user">
<div class="calendar-param hidden" allmemberregistid="40612" calendarid="40612" displayname="ログインユーザー" ownerid="40519"></div>
<div class="loginuser_data">
<dl class="user-table">
<dt><img alt="" src="/o/kview-scheduler-web/images/icon04.png"></dt>
<dd><span class="loginuser_user">ログインユーザー</span></dd>
<dt class="tool_mobile"><img onclick="monthlyClicked();" alt="" src="/o/kview-scheduler-web/images/icon05.png"></dt>
<dd></dd> 
</dl> 
</div> 
</td>

<td class="col-user">
<div class="calendar-param hidden" allmemberregistid="40622" calendarid="40622" displayname="他人" ownerid="39653"></div>
<div class="groupuser_data"> 
<dl class="user-table"> 
<dt><img alt="" src="/o/kview-scheduler-web/images/icon04.png"></dt>
<dd><span class="groupuser_user">他人</span></dd> 
<dt class="user_post"><img alt="" src="/o/kview-scheduler-web/images/icon07.png"></dt>
<dd class="user_post"><span class="position">役職</span></dd>
<dt class="user_division"><img alt="" src="/o/kview-scheduler-web/images/icon08.png"></dt>
<dd class="user_division"><span class="department">所属</span></dd> 
</dl>
</div>
</td>

<td class="col-user">
<div class="calendar-param hidden" allmemberregistid="246147" calendarid="246147" displayname="会議室" ownerid="246144"></div> 
<div class="groupuser_data"> 
<dl class="user-table"> 
<dt><img alt="" src="/o/kview-scheduler-web/images/icon08.png"></dt> 
<dd><span class="groupuser_user">会議室</span>
<dd class="reserve-size"></dd> 
</dl> 
</div> 
</td>
```

Comment: 関連する HTML や CSS のコードと、期待する動作を教えていただけませんか？

Comment: 2個目の `else if` の部分に条件式が無いのが気になります

Comment: eles ifの時は何も処理しないようにしたいです。

Comment: `else if`を使うなら条件式が必要ですし、「何も処理しない」ならその`else if`は不要な気がします (単に`if-else`で済むはず)。 / 質問文は後からでも [編集] できるので、関連するHTMLやCSSはコメント欄では無く質問本文に追記してみてください。

Comment: ”else if{” てif文の条件が無いので、javascriptが構文エラーで止まっていると思うのですが？

Comment: iconName.indexOf('icon07.png')の画像データがある時は<option value="40610" selected="">にselectのデータが入らない処理したいのでどうしても処理を発生しない条件がほしいです。

Comment: `ownerid`属性が付与された要素や、`user-table`クラスが付与された要素、その子孫要素の`dt`要素や`img`要素など、関連している HTML が不足していると思います。関連する HTML を追記してください。もしどこが関連しているかわからないのであれば、問題が再現可能なコードを追記してください。

Comment: html以前にelse ifで処理をしないことは可能なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

構文自体が間違っているコードだけを質問中に記載されても何をしたいのか判断できません。「`iconName.indexOf('icon07.png')`の画像データがある時は`<option value="40610" selected="">`にselectのデータが入らない処理したい」と言った重要な情報はコメントだけでなく質問本文に記載してください。

問題は3通りの分岐をしたいのに`true`か`false`の2通りしかない中間変数`isHuman`を導入していることのように思われます。(`isHuman`がどこにも宣言されていないのも気になりますが、それはまた別の話。)`isHuman`なんて無理に使う必要はないように思うのですが?

```
if( iconName.indexOf('icon04.png') != -1 ) {
    url += 'allGroupUuserList=' + calendarId;
} else if( iconName.indexOf('icon07.png') != -1 ) {
    //Do nothing.
} else {
    url += 'allfacilitieList=' + calendarId;
}
```

あるいは、こう書いても良いでしょう。

```
if( iconName.indexOf('icon04.png') != -1 ) {
    url += 'allGroupUuserList=' + calendarId;
} else if( iconName.indexOf('icon07.png') == -1 ) { //<- `==`にしている
    url += 'allfacilitieList=' + calendarId;
}
```

---

`if`の後ろには必ず条件を明示してやる必要があります。あなたの心の中にある「なんとなくこう動いてくれたら良いな」と言う漠然とした願望をJavaScriptの処理系が推定・斟酌してくれることはありません。

Comment: 返事が遅れましたが解決しました。ありがとうございます。